# can I use JSONP on same domain

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I have a RESTful web service and jquery plugin that talks to the service. The domains are different so I've implemented JSONP and everything works fine.

I'm just working on a couple of changes and have hosted my test client and test service onto localhost but my JSONP callbacks are no longer being called.

here is my jquery call.

```
var urlbase = 'http://localhost:8080';

$.getJSON(urlbase + '/Geography/Countries?callback=?', function (results) {
    alert(results);
    // populate the country lookup
    $.each(results, function (key, value) {
        $('select#countrylookup')
          .append($('<option></option>')
          .attr('value', value.Code)    
          .text(value.Name));
    });
```

I know for a fact that the service is being called and results are being returned because my service breakpoints are being hit and I can see the request/response in fiddler/F12 tools.

If (as I suspect) I need JSON for 'local domain' and JSONP for cross-domain what strategy do others employ when testing? Obviously I don't want any if(domain==local) style code anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Turns out that my problem lies within the VS2010 web server. if I host the site in local IIS no problem at all. Even using the original getJSON.

I've had this running now a couple of days and all seems to be fine. I never mentioned in my original question about the use of VS2010 and WebDev.WebServer40.exe which I probably should of.

To answer the actual question: Yes, you can use JSONP on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

The `getJSON` method will determine if it's a cross domain call from the URL, so you can't use it to make a JSONP call to the same domain. Use the `ajax` method so that you can specify that it should use JSONP using the `crossDomain` property:

```
$.ajax({
  url: urlbase + '/Geography/Countries?callback=?',
  cache: false,
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function (results) {
    alert(results);
    // populate the country lookup
    $.each(results, function (key, value) {
      $('select#countrylookup')
        .append($('<option></option>')
        .attr('value', value.Code)    
        .text(value.Name));
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time help out. Unfortunately I'm still can't get this working, I get a 400 Bad Request when making a local request.

Comment: Update: Turns out that my problem lies within the VS2010 web server. if I host the site in local IIS no problem at all. Even using the original getJSON. I'll do some more checks make sure I'm correct.

Comment: Upvoted this answer because although it didn't solve my actual problem, I was not aware of 'crossDomain' setting of $.ajax